# Convert timezone in Ruby

Tags: ruby, timezone

I have a Ruby process that makes a log file:

```
operation completed at #{Time.now}
```

This generates a log file that contains:

```
operation completed at 2014-04-23 01:51:16 +0200
```

But the Ruby process runs on a server that is far from me, and I have another timezone.  I have +05 timezone, and I want to see:

```
2014-04-23 03:51:16 +0500
```

What I should write instead of `#{Time.now}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind for me is:

```
DateTime.now.new_offset('+5:00').strftime('%F %T %z')
```

You'll have to `require 'date'` first.